# MSCRM: How to qualify a lead using the REST Endpoint?

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

My task is to sync data from our web DB (mySQL) into our on-premises MS Dynamics CRM 2011 system.

At present I am adding records using PHP script to create JSON encoded data and post it using CURL. The URL I am using looks like this

http://crm.server/org_name/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/LeadSet

This all works fine and I get back a guid for future data changes.

I now need to start qualifying the Leads into Accounts and Contacts if they have progressed through a purchase.

How do I qualify a lead via the REST services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QualifyLeadRequest` message is not available with the REST endpoint.

You need to use SOAP, here an example:

http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/11/qualify-lead-and-automatically-create.html